# How to add new sourceset with gradle kotlin-dsl

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to add a sourceset `src/gen/java`. With groovy this is rather easy and already described in https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-use-gradle-with-generated-sources/9401/5

```
sourceSets {
   gen {
        java.srcDir "src/gen/java"
    }
}
```

But I stuck with the kotlin-dsl to add a new one. All I've got is:

```
java {
    sourceSets {

    }
}
```

Can anyone help here to

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
java.sourceSets.create("src/gen/java")
```

Hope it's what you need!

Comment: Thx. Seems not to work. It seems to be a valid but sources are not compiled.

Comment: Hm, after having the solution for my problem it turns out, that I don't need a new sourceset (your answer is correct to add a new sourceset), but to have a new source-folder within the existing `main` sourceset

Comment: On Gradle 6, can't use this anymore, java.sourceSets no longer exists

Answer (score 33):

The answer of @s1m0nw1 is correct  to add a new sourceset.
But to just add a new source-folder in an existing sourceset, this can be used:

```
java.sourceSets["main"].java {
    srcDir("src/gen/java")
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. How did you find this answer? Where is it documented?

Comment: By playing around after the answer from @s1m0nw1

Comment: The eclipse kotlin editor and plugin are not complete and they are buggy. They do not provide code completion hints. I have stopped using eclipse and now switched to IntelliJ Idea, which does let me see the internals of Gradle-Kotlin-DSL implementation API so I can discover the API calls available to me. The lack of proper documentation has been frustrating, but now hopefully with IntelliJ's code completion hints; that will not be a big limitation.

Comment: I'm using a submodule as a kotlin library in my kotlin project. Leaving off the first part `java` worked for me. ie `sourceSets["main"].java {
    srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
}`

Comment: sourceSets["main"].java {
        srcDir("$buildDir/generated/openapi/src/main/java/com/globalfinancingsolutions/network")
    }
worked for me

Answer (score 21):

Worked for me on Gradle 4.10.2:

```
sourceSets.getByName("main") {
    java.srcDir("src/main/java")
    java.srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
}
sourceSets.getByName("test") {
    java.srcDir("src/test/java")
    java.srcDir("src/test/kotlin")
}
```

The codes above can also be used in `subprojects` block.

Answer (score 15):

Worked for me on Gradle 4.10.2:

```
sourceSets.create("integrationTest") {
    java.srcDir("src/integrationTest/java")
    java.srcDir("build/generated/source/apt/integrationTest")
    resources.srcDir("src/integrationTest/resources")
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea why I get the error `The SourceSet 'libs' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin.` when I call `create("libs")`?

Answer (score 11):

kotlin-dsl

```
sourceSets {
        this.getByName("androidTest"){
            //Adds the given source directory to this set.
            this.java.srcDir("src/mock/java")
        }
        this.getByName("test"){
            this.java.srcDir("src/mock/java")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add a source set with the name "test-integration" and the source directory `src/test-integration/kotlin`. I was able to accomplish that by combining the two pre-existing answers:

```
java.sourceSets.create("test-integration").java {
    srcDir("src/test-integration/kotlin")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I had before:

```
main.kotlin.srcDirs = main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
test.kotlin.srcDirs = test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
test.resources.srcDirs = ['testresources']
```

Above now translates to:

```
sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDirs("src")
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs("resources")
    }
}
test {
    java {
        srcDirs("test")
    }
    resources {
        srcDirs("testresources")
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Gradle 7.5:

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.sourceSets {
            create("gen"){
                java.srcDir("src/gen/java")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering how to do in `Jetpack Compose + Jvm` application:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.4.1"
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            kotlin.srcDir("src/jvmMain/kotlin")
            resources.srcDir("src/jvmMain/res")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bets way os to use [jvm-test-suite](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) plugin e.g.:

```kotlin
plugins {
    // ..
    `jvm-test-suite`
}

testing {
    suites {
        register("konsistTest", JvmTestSuite::class) {
            dependencies {
                // Add 'main' source set dependency (optional)
                implementation(project())

                // Add Source set specific dependencies
                implementation("com.lemonappdev:konsist:0.11.0")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `konsistTest` is the name of the new source set. Now just create directory with the same name in IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the "main" build, the Kotlin build.gradle.kts needs the following format to add subfolders for Android layout .xml files (for cleaning up the project folders):

from https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#kts

```
//if you add another subfolder in the res/layouts/... folder, you need
//to add it to this section, relative to the build.gradle.kts file:
//so, to add subfolder 'foo', add the line:
//      res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/foo/")
//don't forget to add the "layout" (no 's') as a subfolder within that
//to properly populate the resource lists for any R.layout.[...] call!
sourceSets {
    getByName("main") {
        java {
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/xxxx/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/yyyy/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/zzzz/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/aaaa/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/bbbb/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/cccc/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/dddd/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/eeee/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/layouts/")
            res.srcDir("/src/main/res/")

        }
    }
}
```