# sourceSets with gradle kotlin DSL in grade 4.10rc

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am using the following code:

```
java.sourceSets["main"].java {
    srcDir("src/main/extraSource")
}
```

works perfectly in gradle 4.9, but in 4.10 rc1 gives the following error:

```
  Line 5: java.sourceSets["main"].java {
               ^ Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
                   public val Project.sourceSets: SourceSetContainer defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
```

Any ideas? Has there been a change to what is needed?
Many other answers (eg. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419817/how-to-add-new-sourceset-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl)  and every suggested answer to this question) will also need updates if this has changed

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Gradle forums or posting a bug report?

Comment: not yet....wondered if it was a known change

Comment: Same issue here I asked on Kotlin Slack in #gradle channel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an expected breaking change and is listed at https://docs.gradle.org/4.10-rc-2/release-notes.html#changes-to-the-gradle-kotlin-dsl

But unfortunately it's missing in the Kotlin DSL release notes, it'll be fixed for 4.10 GA.

In a nutshell, `java.sourceSets` is now `sourceSets`. For your example the fixed script is:

```
sourceSets["main"].java {
    srcDir("src/main/extraSource")
}
```

It’s a change in `gradle/gradle`, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/5867 for some background.